# Angular-js post always getting error(0) as response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angularjs

Thanks for advance

Hi Tried angular-js http post function but always am getting 0 as error response ,i tried lot but it won't help ,so please give me idea to fix the issue.

I used following files

```js
var app = angular.module('angularPostPHP', []);
app.controller('regCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.login = function () {
var request = $http({
    method: 'post',
    url:'http://localhost/HAP_testing/Registration.php',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'},
    data: {
        email: $scope.UserName,
        pass: $scope.Pwd
    }
});
/* Check whether the HTTP Request is successful or not. */
request.success(function (data) {
   // document.getElementById("message").textContent = "You have login successfully with email "+data;
    alert("done"+data);
});

request.error(function(status)
{
 alert("Error"+status);
});

}

});
```

and

```html
<?php  
    // check username or password from database
    $postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
    $request = json_decode($postdata);
    $email = $request->UserName;
    $password = $request->pwd;
    if($email == "dhaya" && $password== "dd"){
     echo "1";
    }
    else {
     echo "dhaya";
    }
 
?>
```

Comment: Is there a reason you're doing file_get_contents on php://input?  I think $postdata = $_POST; should work just fine?  Also, I believe there is no need for json_decode when you use the method I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is here:

```
$email = $request->UserName;
$password = $request->pwd;
```

You passed this data:

```
data: {
    email: $scope.UserName,
    pass: $scope.Pwd
}
```

So I would think that would have to be:

```
$email = $request->email;
$password = $request->pass;
```

One way to do this would probably be:

```
// check username or password from database

$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['pass'];

if($email == "dhaya" && $password== "dd"){
    echo "1";
}
else {
    echo "dhaya";
}
```

**Edited:**
Changed pwd to pass

**Edit:**

I've confirmed that this works with the following curl request:

```
curl -d "email=dhaya&pass=dd" "chase.phpdev.gurutech.ws/question_test.php"
```

Returns "1".  I didn't setup and test the angular. But I've found at least 1 issue.

Comment: while i access same url in browser it's working  but not works in angular    $http.get("http://localhost/HAP_testing/Registration.php?email=dhaya&pass=dd")
            .success(function(data){
               // $scope.data = data;
                alert("successfully"+data);
            })
            .error(function() {
               alert("Error");
            });
}

Comment: @dhaya The data you post in the angular does not match the keys you're looking for in PHP.  Which is what I was pointing out.  Perhaps when you access the URL via the browser it works because the post data contains the correct keys?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone,finally i got fixed. it happening because of request data.

```js
var app = angular.module('angularPostPHP', []);
app.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

$scope.login = function () {
var request = $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url:'../HAP_testing/Loginphp.php',
    // headers: {'Authorization': 'Token token=xxxxYYYYZzzz'}
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;'},
    data:  $.param({
            email: $scope.username,
            pass: $scope.password
        }),
});
/* Check whether the HTTP Request is successful or not. */
request.success(function (data) {
    alert("done");
});

request.error(function(status)
{
 alert("Error"+status.code);
});
```